# Set selected item of spinner programmatically

Tags: android, spinner

I am working on an android project and I am using a spinner which uses an array adapter which is populated from the database.

I can't find out how I can set the selected item programmatically from the list. For example if, in the spinner I have the following items:

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

How would I programmatically make Category 2 the selected item when the screen is created. I was thinking it might be similar to c# I.E Spinner.SelectedText = "Category 2" but there doesn't seem to be any method similar to this for Android.

Comment: Please follow this link :
[How to set selection on spinner item][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358563/how-to-maintain-spinner-state-in-android/23776382#23776382

Comment: You can pass your index into `spinner.setSelection()`. That would work just fine. You can also create a method that can help you match your indexes to their actual strings.

Answer (score 889, accepted):

Use the following:
`spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX_OF_CATEGORY2)`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, while I was doing this I also found a way of getting the index without needing to loop through the adapter. I used the following ``mySpinner.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getPosition("Category 2"));``

Comment: in case you dont have the adapter to reference.

      mySpinner.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)mySpinner.getAdapter()).getPosition("Value"));

Comment: sexSpinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(mUser.getGender()) == -1 ? 0 : adapter.getPosition(mUser.getGender()));

Comment: This doesn't work if the Spinner has an onItemSelectedListener(). The Listener won't be called.

Answer (score 99):

No one of these answers gave me the solution, only worked with this:

```
mySpinner.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mySpinner.setSelection(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: I call SetSelection() just after setAdapter(). This display the 1st item always (Android 2.3), even the good one is selected in the dropView. Your solution did it for me.

Answer (score 46):

```
public static void selectSpinnerItemByValue(Spinner spnr, long value) {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) spnr.getAdapter();
    for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getCount(); position++) {
        if(adapter.getItemId(position) == value) {
            spnr.setSelection(position);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the above like:

```
selectSpinnerItemByValue(spinnerObject, desiredValue);
```

& of course you can also select by index directly like

```
spinnerObject.setSelection(index);
```

Comment: An error with this code is that @Boardy want the selection of `Category 2` which I suppose is a String (assuming he tried using `Spinner.SelectedText = "Category 2"`) but the above code is for a `long`.

Comment: He is populating the categories from the database there must be an ID for each category.

Comment: Why assume it is a CursorAdapter? SpinnerAdapter works just as well.

Comment: I think you have a mistake here, it should be `adapter.getItem(position)`, not `adapter.getItemId(position)`.

Answer (score 34):

Some explanation (at least for Fragments - never tried with pure Activity). Hope it helps someone to understand Android better.

Most popular answer by [Arun George](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically/11072595#11072595) is correct but don't work in some cases. 
The answer by [Marco HC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically/21972242#21972242) uses Runnable wich is a last resort due to additional CPU load.

The answer is - you should simply **choose correct place to call to setSelection()**, for example it **works** for me:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    yourSpinner.setSelection(pos);
 }
```

**But it won't work in onCreateView()**. I suspect that is the reason for the interest to this topic.

The secret is that with Android you can't do anything you want in any method - oops:( - components may just not be ready. As another example - you can't scroll ScrollView neither in onCreateView() nor in onResume() (see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635834/android-scrollto-does-not-work-in-onresume-method/25291102#25291102))

Answer (score 18):

To find a value and select it:

```
private void selectValue(Spinner spinner, Object value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(value)) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Why don't you use your values from the DB and store them on an ArrayList and then just use:

```
yourSpinner.setSelection(yourArrayList.indexOf("Category 1"));
```

Answer (score 13):

The optimal solution is:

```
    public String[] items= new String[]{"item1","item2","item3"};
    // here you can use array or list 
    ArrayAdapter adapter= new ArrayAdapter(Your_Context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    final Spinner itemsSpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.itemSpinner);
itemsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To get the position of the item automatically add the following statement

```
itemsSpinner.setSelection(itemsSpinner.getPosition("item2"));
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getPosition' in 'Spinner'

Comment: For `getPosition()` use adpater like `spinnerAdapter.getPosition()`. It will resolve your problem. @PedroJoaquín

Answer (score 7):

You can make a generic method for this kind of work as I do in my UtilityClass which is

```
public void SetSpinnerSelection(Spinner spinner,String[] array,String text) {
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if(array[i].equals(text)) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily set like this: `spinner.setSelection(1)`, instead of 1, you can set any position of list you would like to show.

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin I found a simple solution using a lambda:

```
spinnerObjec.post {spinnerObjec.setSelection(yourIndex)}
```

Comment: There are twenty-four existing answers to this question, including an accepted answer with 843 (!!!) upvotes. Are you sure your answer hasn't already been provided? If not, why might someone prefer your approach over the existing approaches proposed? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities? Are there scenarios where your approach is better suited?

Answer (score 5):

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter so I have to duplicate the data for use the respose in this post.  So, I recommend you try this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < spinnerRegion.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    if (spinnerRegion.getItemIdAtPosition(i) == Integer
        .valueOf(signal.getInt(signal
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("id_region")))) {
        spinnerRegion.setSelection(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

I think that is a real way

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use in Kotlin:

```
spinner.setSelection(resources.getStringArray(R.array.choices).indexOf("Choice 1"))
```

Comment: if `indexOf` can not make a match, then it returns `-1`, which appears to result in the default value being the selected by `spinner.setSelection`. I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 3):

I know that is already answered, but simple code to select one item, very simple:

```
spGenre.setSelection( ( (ArrayAdapter) spGenre.getAdapter()).getPosition(client.getGenre()) );
```

Answer (score 3):

This is work for me.

```
 spinner.setSelection(spinner_adapter.getPosition(selected_value)+1);
```

Comment: Because it’s start from 0 so we have to add one for getting right answer

Answer (score 3):

*This is stated in comments elsewhere on this page but thought it useful to pull it out into an answer:*

When using an adapter, I've found that the `spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX_OF_CATEGORY2)` needs to occur ***after*** the `setAdapter` call; otherwise, the first item is always the initial selection.

```
// spinner setup...
spinnerObject.setAdapter(myAdapter);
spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX_OF_CATEGORY2);
```

This is confirmed by reviewing the AbsSpinner [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/java/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java) for `setAdapter`.

Comment: Of course, you can select an item only after the adapter has been filled.

Answer (score 3):

This Worked For me:

```
mySpinner.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mySpinner.setSelection(position);

        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of contacts the you can go for this:

```
((Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).setSelection(spinnerContactPersonDesignationAdapter.getPosition(schoolContact.get(i).getCONT_DESIGNATION()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (int x = 0; x < spRaca.getAdapter().getCount(); x++) {
            if (spRaca.getItemIdAtPosition(x) == reprodutor.getId()) {
                spRaca.setSelection(x);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of text to explain your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time `spinner.setSelection(i); //i is 0 to (size-1) of adapter's size`
doesn't work. If you just call `spinner.setSelection(i);`

It depends on your logic.

If view is fully loaded and you want to call it from interface I suggest you to call

```
spinner.setAdapter(spinner_no_of_hospitals.getAdapter());
spinner.setSelection(i); // i is 0 or within adapter size
```

Or if you want to change between activity/fragment lifecycle, call like this

```
spinner.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    spinner.setSelection(i);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Kotlin extension I am using:

```
fun Spinner.setItem(list: Array<CharSequence>, value: String) {
    val index = list.indexOf(value)
    this.post { this.setSelection(index) }
}
```

Usage:

```
spinnerPressure.setItem(resources.getTextArray(R.array.array_pressure), pressureUnit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this by passing the index of the desired spinner item in the setSelection function of spinner. For example:

spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX_OF_CATEGORY).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this code saved my day:

```
public static void selectSpinnerItemByValue(Spinner spnr, long value) {
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = spnr.getAdapter();
    for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getCount(); position++) {
        if(adapter.getItemId(position) == value) {
            spnr.setSelection(position);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do this.  adapter has a getPosition(item) call that returns int position.

Answer (score 0):

I had made some extension function of `Spinner` for loading data and tracking item selection.

**Spinner.kt**

```
fun <T> Spinner.load(context: Context, items: List<T>, item: T? = null) {
    adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items).apply {
        setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    }

    if (item != null && items.isNotEmpty()) setSelection(items.indexOf(item))
}

inline fun Spinner.onItemSelected(
    crossinline itemSelected: (
        parent: AdapterView<*>,
        view: View,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) -> Unit
) {
    onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            itemSelected.invoke(parent, view, position, id)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usaage Example**

```
val list = listOf("String 1", "String 2", "String 3")
val defaultData = "String 2"

// load data to spinner
your_spinner.load(context, list, defaultData)

// load data without default selection, it points to first item
your_spinner.load(context, list)

// for watching item selection
your_spinner.onItemSelected { parent, view, position, id -> 
    // do on item selection
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mySpinner.setSelection(position);
}
```

It's similar to @sberezin's solution but calling setSelection() in onStart().

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue since yesterday.Unfortunately the first item in the array list is shown by default in spinner widget.A turnaround would be to find the previous selected item with each element in the array list and swap its position with the first element.Here is the code.

```
OnResume()
{
int before_index = ShowLastSelectedElement();
if (isFound){
      Collections.swap(yourArrayList,before_index,0);
   }
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CurrentActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourArrayList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;                    yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
...
private int ShowLastSelectedElement() {
        String strName = "";
        int swap_index = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<societies.size();i++){
            strName = yourArrayList.get(i);
            if (strName.trim().toLowerCase().equals(lastselectedelement.trim().toLowerCase())){
                swap_index = i;
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
        return swap_index;
    }
```