# Spinner with ArrayAdapter<String> showing null pointer exception?

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

The question is quite obvious but still none of them help me to solve.
I'm using a spinner that need to filled with string by array adapter. But while running application, `null pointer exception` occurred. Also i've declared spinner and `ArrayAdapter<String>` as `global variable` and defined it in `onCreate method`. But still its showing null pointer exception. Could anyone please have a look at my code to see what the problem is and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
String elements[] ={"- Select -","Iron", "Bronze", "Magnesium"};
Spinner fSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> adp;
```

in onCreate :

```
fSpinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
    adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,elements);
    fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

[image: logcat]

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: @Simple Plan look my edits for logcat

Comment: @AB what is at line 107 in your `MainActivity`? or post your `MainActivity`

Comment: Verify if you have added correct layout...

Comment: @Simple Plan line 107: fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);

Comment: @Androidbeginner it's means your `fSpinner` is `NULL` at this position.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar Yes i've added correct layout

Comment: @Simple Plan Yes, but i've already added items to array adapter and set that to Spinner

Comment: @Androidbeginner If you have added correct layout then this is impossible for NPE. Clear your application and try again. Make sure the spinner is in your layout code... Here your spinner is null not adapetr

Comment: @Androidbeginner but your spinner is not bind to adapter. your spinner is null.

Comment: @Simple Plan So, how i can do that, thanks

Comment: try this new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, elements);

Comment: @raj still same error: null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working for me

```
List<String> elements=new ArrayList<String>();
elements.add("- Select -");
elements.add("Iron");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt= new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, elements);
adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapt);
```

Comment: I've put this spinner in dialog box, after closing dialog box when reopen dialog box the spinner always show `-Select-` instead of what i've selected, so is there any way i can do the same, thanks

Comment: you have to now save spinner state and save it in shared prefrences

Comment: post another question for that and give link you will find answer

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358563/how-to-maintain-spinner-state-in-android/16358873#16358873

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<Charsequence> adt= new ArrayAdapter<Charsequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Make necessary changes and try the above code.