# How change to the next position in a spinner of android?

Tags: android, position, set, spinner

I have a spinner with 3 options. The first option shows up with the method onCreate. When the first option is selected, in an EditText I write something, and click in a button to save it. Well, my question is if I can change the spinner to the next option when I press the button.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set an OnClickListener to your Button. In the onClick method set the selection of the spinner to the current selected value and add "1"

```
 myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            mySpinner.setSelection(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
```

}