# How to select an item in a spinner using a button

Tags: android, button, spinner

I created a `spinner` with 5 items and I also created 5 buttons. What I want to do is to associate a button to an item in the spinner. So when I click a button, a corresponding item will be selected. For example:

I have 5 items in my spinner:

```
hey, hi, ho, hello, sup
```

I have 5 buttons:

```
btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5
```

`btn5` is associated to `sup`. So when I click `btn5`, `sup` should be selected in the spinner. How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically this should help you :)

Comment: Show us what you already tried. This sounds like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an `onClickListener` on each button calling the following function with the `button id` as parameter:

```
function switchSpinner(int id){
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    int pos=-1;
    switch(id){
        R.id.btn1:
            pos=0;
            break;
        R.id.btn2:
            pos=1;
            break;
        R.id.btn3:
            pos=2;
            break;
        R.id.btn4:
            pos=3;
            break;
        R.id.btn5:
            pos=4;
            break;  
    }
    spinner.setSelection(pos);
    spinner.requestLayout() //add this only if the spinner does not change    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enter hard code values for spinner then you need to do this

```
  Button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
          // Here you need specify which item of spinner you need to select.
         spinner.setSelection(0);
       }
    });
```

Like this if you have 5 buttons you need to create 5 click event with setSelect(position) event.

You can do this by different ways as you prefer. I think using this you will have more control.

For dynamic spinner you need different logic where you need to create button dynamically and add click event them dynamically with index of your custom or base adapter.