# How to call other variables in spinner functionality?

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("none,i am healthy");
        list.add("Diabetes");
        list.add("cancer");
        list.add("HIV/AIDS");
        list.add("Tuberculosis");
        list.add("Coronary Artery");
        list.add("respiratory disease");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
//        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                List <String>list = new  ArrayList <String>();
                list.add("Diabetes");
                list.add("cancer");
                list.add("HIV/AIDS");
                list.add("Tuberculosis");
                list.add("respiratory disease");
                list.add("Coronary Artery");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

                if (list.get(position).equals("Diabetes")) {
                    String name = editText.getText().toString();

                    int c = b;


                    int x = c - 5 ;
                    editText3.setText(name + " you might die in the year" + c + "");
```

As you can see i have called in editText3 after a selection made by the user but as you can also see that i have defined int c = b . where as the b is the variable used in button click listener . i am also giving the code of button click listener

```
 button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {





                    String name = editText.getText().toString();


                    if (yes.isChecked()) {
                        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                        int c;
                        int b ;
                        int l;
                        l = 80 ;
                        int y ;
                        y = l - age ;

                        c = y - 7;
                        final int z;
                        b = 2016 + c;

                        editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year" + b) + "");

                    } else {
                        if (no.isChecked()) {
                            int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                            int c;
                            int b;
                            int l;
                            l = 80;
                            int y;
                            y = l - age;
                            c = y + 10;

                            b = 2016 + c;
                            editText3.setText((name + "you might die in the year" + b) + "");
                        }
                    }


                }
            });
```

now in this button you can see that the ultimate result was b . 
now i want to use the int value of b in spinner . i.e. the spinner would add or decrease the value of the variable b on selection from the user .

Comment: Can you check this [Set selected item of spinner programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically).

Is it what do you want to do ?!

Comment: Add one global variable outside the method and add resultofB = b; after you update the b, so you can use int c = resultofB;

Comment: Right. Or if those are in differente Classes u can create an instance of one class in the other

Comment: please explain it in detail :(