# Check a radio button according to a text

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button

In Android Studio, I want to check a radio button according to a text fetched from a table. Like, check 'MALE' if it's MALE in table or 'FEMALE' for FEMALE. Is it possible? If possible, how can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You may have a view like this:

```
   <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/gender" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:checkedButton="@+id/block_scenario_off"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="@string/male" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left" 
            android:onClick="@string/on_click"/>
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="@string/female" 
            android:onClick="@string/on_click"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/female"/>

    </RadioGroup>
```

Now on the function write like this:

```
rgOption = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender);
String mGender = // get text whether it is male or female
if(mGender.equals("Male"))
   rgOption.check(R.id.male);
else 
   rgOption.check(R.id.female);
```

Comment: i think you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically