# Unchecked cast spinnerAdapter to arrayAdapter<String> warning

Tags: android, spinner, warnings

I need to set the selected item on a spinner using the value of a String.
At the moment I use this (hint found here: [Set selected item of spinner programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically)).

```
Spinner nudSpinner = (Spinner)nud.findViewById(R.id.spinUnity);
EditText nudEText = (EditText)nud. findViewById(R.id.etxtUnityName);
nudSpinner.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)nudSpinner.getAdapter()).getPosition(unities.get(position).split(" ")[0]));
```

It works fine but it gives me the following warning:

```
Unchecked cast: 'android.widget.SpinnerAdapter' to 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter<java.lang.String>'
Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:

  void f(HashMap map) {
    map.put("key", "value");
  }

Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.
```

How can I solve the warning?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type safety: Unchecked cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast)

Comment: But you set it first with `nudSpinner.setAdapter(adapter)` .... so why didn't you store reference to it (`adapter`)? If you do this there would be no need for cast at all.

Comment: @Selvin I don't set the adapter...

Comment: if you did not set the adapter so why do you want to call `getAdapter()` at all? and whats the point in calling: `getPosition(unities.get(position)`?