# How to display a different item from spinner initially

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am trying to display a different value from a spinner.

```
Spinner initialCity =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.initialCity);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SDPSalaryCalcActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fromCities));
```

It displays items from my string Array.

```
<string-array name="fromCities">

<item>city 1</item>
<item>city 2</item>
<item>city 3</item>

</string-array>
```

I would like instead of displaying `city1` initially to display the second item.

Thank you.

Comment: Couldn’t you just list them in the order you want them to appear?

Comment: Have you tried `initialCity.setSelection(1)` (1 because index starts at Zero) after the you have set the adapter :: `initialCity.setAdapter(myAdapter )`?

Comment: Thank you initialCity.setSelection(1) worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set selected item of spinner programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically)

Comment: @LAD :: Indeed you are correct. Looks like a duplicate, therefore I am removing my answer.