# Can I select spinner item not attached to layout? it is in Spinner.MODE_DIALOG

Tags: android, spinner

This code in an activity, I need to select spinner item from this;
I'm getting error when I clicking on an spinner item: Error Log is "E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null"

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String phoneNumber = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            etPhone.setText(phoneNumber);
            Log.d("SPINNER", phoneNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Log.d("SPINNER", (String) parent.getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is issue?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072595/6891563

Comment: no log is written into log cat ; I've not attached the spinner to layout. Is it possible to select item from unattached spinner item. I'm getting error "E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null"

Comment: @Khemraj  Is it possible to select item from unattached spinner item. I'm getting error "E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null" please have a look