# How to set value from selected in android spinner based on database value?

Tags: android, android-spinner

how to set spinner selected value from database,I have attached the below code and attached the Spinner sting array,this string array only saved from database and same spinner to set the selected string array ,kindly help me.

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.net.Uri;

    public class Doc40Fragment extends Fragment   {
  private Spinner mestimationspin, Uomspin;
      private String[] yesNo = new String[]{"yes", "no"};
        private String[] avareage = new String[]{"GOOD", "POOR", "AVERAGE"};
        private String[] fitUnfit = new String[]{"Fit", "Unfit"};
        private String[] uom = new String[]{" ", "Nos", "Tonnes"};
        private String[] ras = new String[]{"Field wetness", "Low earthing up", "Power line crossing", "Ryot unwilling", "Small plot"};
      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doc40, container, false);
 Uomspin = view.findViewById(R.id.uom_edit);

     Uomspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

                    String dist_pos = "uom" + i;
                    int resID = getId(dist_pos, R.array.class);
                    final String[] uom = view.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(resID);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> uobAdater = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uom);
                    Uomspin.setAdapter(uobAdater);

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

      return view;
        }
```

Comment: are we trying to set the spinner value? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically

Comment: Uomspin.setSelection(uom.getPosition(Selected_value_fetch_from_database));

Comment: This is not working, please give i want clearly code

Comment: Am a beginner please say to clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void SpinnerSetup() {
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.india_states, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mStateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        mStateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
                String Select_State = "Select State";
                if (!Select_State.matches(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString())){
                    state = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                  }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }



     if (!json_data.isNull("state"))
 {
    User_sate = json_data.getString("state").toString();
    int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(User_sate);
    mStateSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
    }
```