# How to programmaticaly scroll Spinner dropdown menu to make first item visible

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, android-view, android-spinner

Is there a way to scroll spinner's dropdown list to top so first item is visible regardless which item is currently selected?
Obviously I need only to make vistible the item in the list without any selection.

ListView has smoothScrollToPosition() method to display a specific item in the list but spinner seems not to have a similar behavior.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072576/set-selected-item-of-spinner-programmatically

Comment: setSelection(0); can work

Comment: Sorry but I said without perform any selection. setSelection(0) select the first item and this isn't what I need. I want only to scroll dropdown list to make first item visible and then let the user tap on the desidered item.

Comment: No updates for this one @Danilo.NET? I'm trying to fix this now.